# Convert Byte array to pdf with c# code

Tags: c#-4.0, pdf, linq-to-sql, arrays

I have a table with much more binary type column. I have to convert these byte array to pdf. I write this with c# codes as follows:

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        using (CMEntities myEntity = new CMEntities())
        {
            myEntity.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            var r = (from b in myEntity.FileDatas
                     orderby b.Oid
                     where b.Status == null
                     select b).Skip(Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\test\FromBinary\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length).Take(500);
            button5.Text = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\test\FromBinary\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length.ToString();
            int i = 1;
            try
            {
                FileSystemStoreObject fileSystem = new FileSystemStoreObject();
                foreach (var item in r)
                {
                    byte[] a = item.Content;
                    File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\test\FromBinary\" + item.Oid + "-" + item.FileName, a);
                    fileSystem.Oid = item.Oid;
                    fileSystem.FileName = item.FileName;
                    fileSystem.Size = item.size;
                    item.Status = 1;
                    myEntity.FileSystemStoreObjects.AddObject(fileSystem);
                    if (i == 500)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;
                    fileSystem = new FileSystemStoreObject();
                }
                myEntity.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch { }
        }
```

but when my program begin working my some pdf files didn't open. I get error that this file demaged or....
How can I get healthy pdf file?
Please help me.

Comment: Here is a good tutorial , It will help you

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/09/creating-an-asp-net-report-using-visual-studio-2010-part-1.aspx

Comment: I sold my problem many days ago, thank you, @Ankit.

Comment: Then you should post your solution and mark it as the answer, to help others. @ElvinArzumanoğlu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case some people have problems with Pdf too, I suggest to download [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf).

Indeed, you could see that a PDF file must start with `%PDF-` plus version, for example `%PDF-1.4` and ends with `%%EOF`, and the two preceding lines are a byte offset and `startxref`...
If you look into your generated PDF with Notepad++ for example, you could identify if your file is complete or not, and which part is missing.